# Installation boot, Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: 15.04

I saw a lot of people had that error, but I am getting this on the boot, while I am trying to install ubuntu

If I choose instead "try ubuntu" it works but it hangs on the installation at the hd partitioning step

I get the same error even if I just try to check the device for installation errors..

I am using an 8gb usb pen

15.04 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently reinstalling ubuntu on the usb solved the problem

Comment: A sad solution... This same image has problems with the normal boot. It can't find a configuration file...