# Ubuntu live USB installer won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, live-usb

Can anyone help me in regards to the installation of Ubuntu 15.04. First of all I've downloaded the amd64 or the 64-bit version of it, after making a bootable flash drive using the Universal USB installer which is included on the tutorial of Ubuntu I've tried to turn off my laptop and tried to boot the Ubuntu installer on my flash drive by first, entering the BIOS and changing the orders of the device which are going to boot first, so I put USB on first, after that I've turn off the fast boot, and check if the HDD if it is on compatibility mode, so all are set, But when I tried to boot Ive only seen a black screen, it also happened on the i386 version of Ubuntu 15.04. I can't actually find the problem because I'm new to Linux. Please help me through the installation process.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 8 (I'm trying to dual boot it with Linux.)
- Manufacturer: Toshiba Satellite pro c640
- BIOS: InsydeH2O version 03.610.081.00
- CPU: Intel Core i3-2310m @ 2.10Ghz (4cpu's)
- RAM: 4GB
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce 315M

This is the link of the actual picture when I tried to boot.

[image]

I also tried to run it in VirtualBox and the same problem appears just like in the above picture.

Comment: Try pressing `F12` or `Esc` when the computer boots to enter the BIOS boot menu. Here, select the USB drive and hit `enter`.

Comment: Hi Zacharee1, thank you for your immediate reply, but that doesnt seem to be the problem as i have already tried that one, after hitting enter it shows the same black screen with a white blinking horizontal line, It seems that the bios didn't recognized my Flash Drive Since when i have tried to hit F12 i only see USB without the brand of it or the system inside of that flash drive.

Comment: OK. Try using Rufus to burn the drive, instead. https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: Thanks, I will try it first, i'll come back to you for results. wish me luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installation boot, Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613718/installation-boot-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-u)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441)

Answer (score 0):

Your usb is probably corrupted, try re-burning the iso image to your usb. If that doesn't work I would re-download the iso. Also try using a different usb port to boot your machine.